# How can I store photos taken by the user while offline in my Blazor WebAssembly PWA so I can upload them once back online?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I am creating a WebAssembly Progressive Web App which will be used on both Desktop browsers as well as on Mobile devices. The reason that WebAssembly PWA was chosen was because the user will often be in places (such a basements or inside buildings) where they have no web access and so the plan is to implement offline functionality so that anything they do can be uploaded to the server once they come back online.

I can use local storage for temporarily storing database changes, but the problem I have is that the user will be taking photos that will need to somehow be stored, but the local storage maximum limit is generally only about 5 meg and isn't designed for this amount of storage.

How can I temporarily store the images? I was thinking that if the images were in the phones gallery then I could somehow store a link to them and access them from there, but I cant seem to find any way of accessing the gallery from a PWA. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need a data api of some sort on an http or https endpoint.  Like most other browser technologies, webassembly doesn't give you access to the file system of your device, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the photos in indexeddb? You should be able to have enough space allocated for many photos. I'm not sure what the restrictions are from WebAssembly, but that would work just fine in a classic PWA so that should work too in WebAssembly.

LocalStorage is really not the solution to use in 2023.